# Is there a real matrix A such that (Exponential of matrices)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

Is there a real matrix A such that

$$\exp(A) = \begin{bmatrix} -\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & -\beta \end{bmatrix}, \text{ where }\alpha,\beta>0?$$

(Hint): In two dimensions the exponential matrix of

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$

is given by:

$$\exp(A) = e^{\delta}\cos(\Delta)\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + e^{\delta}\frac{\sin(\Delta)}{\Delta}\begin{bmatrix} \phi & b \\ c & -\phi \end{bmatrix},$$

where $\delta=\dfrac{a+d}{2}$, $\phi=\dfrac{a-d}{2}$, $\Delta=\sqrt{\phi^2+bc}$.

Does this exercise only reduce the multiplication of the matrices given in the tip?

Comment: The matrix is diagonal, so its logarithm is $$\begin{bmatrix}\log(-\alpha)&0\\0&\log(-\beta)\end{bmatrix}. $$ If $\alpha,\beta>0$ then $\log(-\alpha)$ and $\log(-\beta)$ are not real numbers.

Comment: A partial answer: $\operatorname{tr}(\exp A) = \sum_{\lambda} \exp(\lambda)$ (with multiplicity). Therefore, if the  eigenvalues of $A$ are real, then $\operatorname{tr}(\exp A)$ is positive.

Comment: Jordan normal form of $A$...

Comment: Then it is not so simple to solve this exercise. could you please explain me better where I can find these results, for example, why I can calculate the logarithm of the eigenvalues ​​directly and find that they are not real?

Comment: there is something wrong with your overall formula. It is giving wrong results when $\phi^2 + bc < 0.$ However, the answer to your question is a matrix with  $\phi^2 + bc < 0.$

Answer (score 2):

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \pi \\
- \pi & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The point is this: by straightforward summing, we can find, for real number $t,$ given

$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & t \\
- t & 0
\end{array}
\right) \; \; ,
$$

we get

$$
e^B =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & \sin t \\
- \sin t & \cos t
\end{array}
\right) \; \; .
$$

That is, even powers of $B$ are diagonal, and odd powers of $B$ are off-diagonal, in fact skew symmetric. We are looking for
$$ e^B = I + B + \frac{1}{2} B^2 +  \frac{1}{6} B^3 +  \frac{1}{24} B^4+  \frac{1}{120} B^5+  \frac{1}{720} B^6 + \cdots  $$
We get the cosines on the diagonal from
$$  I +  \frac{1}{2} B^2 +    \frac{1}{24} B^4+  \frac{1}{720} B^6 + \cdots  $$
and the sines skew-symmetric from
$$  B +   \frac{1}{6} B^3 +   \frac{1}{120} B^5 + \cdots  $$

Comment: Who ever down voted might want to explain it, as it is a perfectly fine answer

Comment: @user251257 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = PJP^{-1}$ be the complex Jordan normal form of $A$. Then, we have $\exp(A) = P\exp(J) P^{-1}$.

The Jordan block structure is (up to permutation) unique. Hence, $\exp(J)$ is also diagonal and (up to permutation) has the diagonal $-\alpha, -\beta$. In particular $J$ is also diagonal with non real valued diagonal component.

As $A$ is real, it follows both eigenvalues are not real, conjugated to each other, and distinct. 
Let $\lambda = x + yi$ denote an eigenvalue. Than, we have
$$ \exp(\lambda) = \underbrace{\exp(x)}_{>0} \exp(yi), $$
which is real and negative if and only if $\exp(yi) = -1$, that is $y=\pi \bmod 2\pi$.
Using the same logic on $\bar \lambda$, we obtain that $\alpha$ needs to be $\beta$.

So there is a solution $A$ if and only if $\alpha = \beta$. In that case $A$ is given by
$$ A = \log(\alpha) I + \log(-I), $$
where $\log(-I)$ is multi-valued.

*Aside:*

- A canonic choice for $\log(-I)$ is given in @WillJagy's answer.
- Once you established $\alpha=\beta$, you can just interpret $A$ as a complex number $z = -\alpha + 0i$ and the question reduces to the complex logarithm.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. Now, does anyone know how to specifically use the exercise tip to solve this problem? For I was intrigued by this result. why is it obtained from $A= \delta I + B$, where $B$ is a matrix with eigenvalues $\phi, - \phi$, when I make the exponential $e^{\delta I}$, it suddenly becomes the number $e^ \delta$, with $\delta = (a+d)/2$, being before it was matrix. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: @RicardoFreire  it really depends on whether you know eigenvalues, how to diagonalize matrices. As I said, there is something wrong with the material you posted as a hint. In particular, when $\phi^2 + bc$ is negative, your hint gives off. As You keep insisting, I will take some time and see if that hint can possibly be correct, at least for my answer matrix with $a=d=0$ and $b=-c=\pi$ Perhaps there is some cancellation of the factors of $i$ that appear...

Comment: @RicardoFreire With
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \pi \\ - \pi & 0 \end{array} \right) $$
your recipe gives
$$ e^A =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cosh \pi & \sinh \pi \\ - \sinh \pi & \cosh \pi \end{array} \right)  $$
which is just wrong.

Comment: The book I'm using to study is Gerald Teschl's ODE and Dynamic Systems. This part of linear equations is very confusing and I am having a lot of difficulty understanding the content. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @RicardoFreire I made a mistake about that $P$ needs to be unitary. I corrected it.

Comment: @RicardoFreire I posted the formula for 2 by 2 $e^A$ from an early version of Teschl's book. You have a later edition: does that formula use $ \cos $ and $\sin$ as you typed above, or is it $\cosh$ and $\sinh \;?$ The latter, as on the page I posted, is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The actual recipe given in Teschl is this, page 63. See that there are explicit notes about what to do when the square root will be of a negative quantity, $$  \cosh  i \Delta  = \cos \Delta \; ,  $$
$$ \frac{\sinh i \Delta}{i \Delta} = \frac{\sin \Delta}{\Delta} \; . $$

Using the symbols below, namely matrix $A,$ then $\delta = \frac{a+d}{2} \; , \; $ $\gamma = \frac{a-d}{2} \; . \; $ With real $t \neq 0,$
$$  \gamma^2 + bc < 0 \; ,  \; \; \mbox{LET} \; \;  t = \sqrt { \;- \left( \gamma^2 + bc\right) \; \; }  $$ 
THEN
$$
e^A =
e^\delta \cos t \; I \; + \; \frac{e^\delta \sin t}{t} \;
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\gamma & b \\
c & -\gamma
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Uses 
$$
\frac{1}{2ict}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\gamma - it & \gamma + it \\
c & c
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\delta - it & 0 \\
0 & \delta + it
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-c & \gamma + it \\
c & - \gamma + it
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]